# Redirect method calls like __getattribute__()?

Tags: python, redirect, methods, subclass

I'm trying to inherit numpy.ndarray, but need to resize the array in a method, but no answer so far  :

[Resize inherited ndarray, inside a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139137/resize-inherited-ndarray-inside-a-method)

So my question then is how to redirect methods to local object.
For attribute you can use **__getattribute__**, **__getattr__** is there similar option for methods ?

something like this :

```
class Blah():

   def __init__(...):
       ......
       self.obj = np.zeros(...)

  def __get_method__(self, method):
      return self.obj.method() ????
```

Comment: Methods (or rather, the functions that produce them) are attributes. `__getattr__` is only called for attributes that can't be found via the normal lookup process, not for intercepting existing attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just inherit from `numpy.array`?

```
class Blah(numpy.array):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        numpy.array.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ....

    def resize(self, ...):
        ....
```

As a hack that might sometimes be more convenient, you can do alternatively

```
class Blah:
    ...
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.obj, name)
```

But this is normally something you would regret later :-}.

**Edit**: To come back to the first (better) way: You can resize in-place. See here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize

Comment: numpy is inherited by **__new__** and some additional logic... resizing in place does not work in inherited class   .... at least I havent found a way .. : ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (40) into shape (20)

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. I see it now here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html. Then I hope you can do it via the second way (`__getattr__`).

Comment: so this will call the method "name" ? what about arguments ?

Comment: Yes, when asking for an attribute that is not in `Blah`, it will call this function and return that attribute from `obj`, e.g. your `numpy.array`. This can just be an integer, but also a method. If it's a method, the call happens exactly as for the native object, including arguments and return value.